# How to store each file in a directory to a datatable in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, csv, datatable, directory, getfiles

What I need to do is to create a new datatable for each file in a directory. 
This is my code:

```
    Dim BackUpDirectory As String = "/c.."
    Dim Dt As New DataTable()
    Dim PDBC As New DataTable()
    Dt.Columns.Add("File", GetType(String))


    For Each filename As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(BackUpDirectory)

        Dim fileinfo As New FileInfo(filename)
        Dt.Rows.Add(fileinfo.Name)
        PDBC = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(filename)
        PDBC.Rows.Add(PDBC.Rows(0), PDBC.Rows(1))

    Next
```

What I'm getting is one datatable which keeps on being overwritten by new csv in the directory. I know I am doing something wrong but as of now, I have no idea how to create new datatable for each csv file in the directory.

In this point, anything would really help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare a DataSet outside of the loop, and add each table that you create inside the loop to the DataSet.